# Curing of polyester resin that did not reach top exothermic temperature

Tags: polymers, catalysis

When working with polyester resins for fiberglass or geloat, there are times where the thickness of the resin on the substrate is not sufficient to get a strong exothermic reaction and achieving a high temperature to "kick". I have been told in the industry to use artificial heat source to help it get to a high enough temperature for a good kick.

My question is: If you are working with a thin layer of resin or the ambient temperature is too low for the resin to kick on its own, and it was not artificially brought up to an appropriate temperature of say 250 degF and the resin stayed at a low ambient temperature of about 45 degF for several days before finally brought up to about 70 degrees, would the resin still cure eventually or will the overall cure be significantly compromised?

This type of scenario can happen a lot when doing minor gelcoat repair outdoors in colder climates.